# Abrir múltiples iframes con distintos urls

Tags: javascript, html5, iframe

Tengo un problema con mi portfolio. Quiero hacer una galería que, al tocar en la `img`, se abra un `iframe` en donde se vea el proyecto que hice. El tema es que cada imagen debería abrir un iframe distinto. Estoy usando un código que solo me permite abrir el primer iframe, y no sé cómo hacer para poder abrir los otros, ya que al clickear en los otros, no se abren.
El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

HTML5:

```
                              <div id="ad1" class="portfolio-item deporte col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-box">
                        <div class="portfolio-image-wrap">
                                    <img id="myImg" src="img/portfolio/img1.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                  <div class="portfolio-caption-mask" id="myDiv">
                                    <div class="portfolio-caption-text">
                                        <div class="portfolio-caption-tb-cell">
                                            <h5 class="alt-title">Texto</h5>
                                            <p>Nombre del proyecto</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>   

                        </div>
                    </div>  
                      <div id="MyModal" class="modal">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <div class="contenido">

                        <iframe style="height: 480px; width: 320px" src="http://url.com/test/proyecto1/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('MyModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];   

 // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
div.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
} 

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
img.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}  

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

var freezeVp = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
}; 
</script>
```

Con este JS, puedo hacer que se abra únicamente el primer iframe, pero no sabría cómo hacer para copiar el código o adaptarlo para que abra todos los iframes. Dejo también la url para ver una demo de mi sitio y para que entiendan mi problema: [demo portfolio](http://kickads.mobi/richmediagallery/index_test_iframe.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puede utilizar las bondades de Bootstrap y Jquery para abrir la modal. Además solo deberá tener 1 modal para todos los proyectos posibles.

Los cambios que deberá hacer en el HTML es. Añadir un atributo data-url a cada una de las imágenes  para saber que `url` cargar en el `iframe` cuando se de `click`. Además añadir `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal"` para abrir la modal respectiva

**Imágenes**

```
<img id="myImg" 
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal"
    data-url="http://kickads.mobi/test/nike/jordan/"
    src="http://kickads.mobi/richmediagallery/img/portfolio/nike_jordan.jpg" alt="" />
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="miModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe src="" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
$('img[data-target="#miModal"]').click(function(){
    // modificamos el src del iframe con el atributo data-url de la imagen clickeada
     $('#miModal').find('iframe').attr('src',$(this).data('url'));
 });
```

**Update**

Revisando su template, haría falta añadir la referencia a bootstrap JS para que funcione la apertura de la modal,  eliminar los atributos `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal" data-url=""`  de la imagen `img` y añadirlos al padre con la clase `portafolio-box` de esta forma.

```
<div class="portfolio-box" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal" data-url="....">
```

El JS funcionaría como esta en la parte superior de mi respuesta.

Comment: Genial, creo que entendí todo! En cuanto al JS que pasaste, lo debo poner una sola vez y eso se aplicará a todos los iframes? O debo copiarlo y pegarlo por cada iframe?

Comment: Solo debes tener un iframe dentro de un modal _(solo requieres de un modal)_ , como está en el código de mi respuesta, el código Js es solo eso, se coloca una sola vez y debería funcionar.

Comment: Genial, voy a modificar el código y ver cómo funciona! Gracias!

Comment: El modal en dónde debo agregarlo?

Comment: En cualquier lugar de su documento HTML, _(pero de preferencia al final)_  eso sí, solo es uno ;)

Comment: Ahí subí los cambios que me sugirió, pero creo que algo mal estoy haciendo, ya que no logro abrir ningún modal con el nuevo código. :/